# Merge objects based on certain attributes and combine(sum) certain other attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge

Let's say I have `MyObject` with attributes `attr_a`, `attr_b` and `attr_c` and `quantity.`

I'd like to combine their quantities if they have the same `attr_a`, `attr_b` and `attr_c`

Here's an example and my approach. Is there a better way to do this? For instance; what if I wanted to retain the ordering of my lists after combining them?

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, attr_a, attr_b, attr_c, quantity):
        self.attr_a = attr_a
        self.attr_b = attr_b
        self.attr_c = attr_c
        self.quantity = quantity

    def __eq__(self, rhs):
        if type(rhs) is type(self):
            return self.attr_a == rhs.attr_a and self.attr_b == rhs.attr_b and self.attr_c == rhs.attr_c
        else:
            return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.attr_a, self.attr_b, self.attr_c))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{}, {}, {}, {}>".format(self.attr_a, self.attr_b, self.attr_c, self.quantity)


from collections import defaultdict

pos1 = [MyObject("AAA", "BBB", "A123", 1000), MyObject("AAA", "CCC", "A123", 2000)]
pos2 = [MyObject("AAA", "BBB", "A123", 2000), MyObject("AAA", "CCC", "A123", -2000), MyObject("AAA", "DDD", "A999", 200)]

merge = defaultdict(int)

for p in pos1 + pos2:
    merge[p] += p.quantity

res = []
for k, v in merge.items():
    k.quantity = v
    res.append(k)

print(res)

"""
Expected output: [<AAA, BBB, A123, 3000>, <AAA, CCC, A123, 0>, <AAA, DDD, A999, 200>]
"""
```

Comment: Personally I do not think that overriding the `__eq__` operator is a good idea here since it means that from now on `MyObject('A', 'B', 'C', 1) == MyObject('A', 'B', 'C', 1425)`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem at least this is consistant with the `__hash__` implementation.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: yes, but I think it is not a good idea to "tailor" aspects to a specific usecase. Usually classes have several use cases, so that means that later, another usecase can not make use of this, and it will result in a lot of "piculiar" situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think it is not a good idea to "tailor" the `__eq__`, etc. functions towards a specific use case: right now it means that `MyObject("AAA", "BBB", "A123", 1000)` is considered equal to `MyObject("AAA", "BBB", "A123", 1425)`. For the usecase of "merging" such objects together, that might work, but that implies other (straightforward) usecases might result in a lot of extra logic.

Another thing I would avoid is *changing* the quantity of an existing `MyObject` in general: you do not know what variables are pointing to that object. As a result this can mean that a list containing `MyObject`s all of a sudden has a list where the `quantities` are different.

It might be better to implement a function like `get_key`:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, attr_a, attr_b, attr_c, quantity):
        self.attr_a = attr_a
        self.attr_b = attr_b
        self.attr_c = attr_c
        self.quantity = quantity

    def get_key(self):
        return (self.attr_a, self.attr_b, self.attr_c)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{}, {}, {}, {}>".format(self.attr_a, self.attr_b, self.attr_c, self.quantity)
```

Then we perform a more or less similar algorithm, but we construct new `MyObject`s:

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(int)

for obj in objs:
    res[obj.get_key()] += obj.quantity

result = [MyObject(*k, v) for k, v in res.items()]
```

Making some sort of `clone` function to copy the `MyObject` together with a new quantity might also improve code design.